# Serialize geometry to GeoJSON with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, geojson

In the ArcObjects developer SDK, I found that the IExternalSerializerGdb2 interface of the JSONSerializerGdb class supports writing to GeoJSON.

> *ArcGIS Developer Help (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase)*
>
> **IExternalSerializerGdb2.WriteRecordSetEx2 Method**
>
> Writes feature
>   recordset for both JSON and GeoJSON format and returns number of
>   records serialized.

I tried this:

```cs
var jsonWriter = new JSONWriterClass();
jsonWriter.WriteToString();

var jsonSerializer = new JSONSerializerGdbClass();
jsonSerializer.InitSerializer(jsonWriter, null);

var recordset = new RecordSetClass();
recordset.SetSourceTable((ITable)featureclass, null);

var sr = ((IGeoDataset)featureclass).SpatialReference;

int count;
((IExternalSerializerGdb2)jsonSerializer).WriteRecordSetEx2(null, recordset, null, sr, out count);
```

But it only seems to write the (ArcGIS) JSON format.

How do I generate GeoJSON?

Comment: Did you try using the [JSONConverterGdb class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#JSONConverterGdb.htm) instead of the `JSONWriterClass`?

Comment: I did now, but `jsonConverterGdb.WriteRecordSet(jsonWriter, null, null, null, recordset, null, true);` gives me the same (ArcGIS) JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but for anyone else who may be looking for a way to do this out of the box with ArcObjects see the following:

```
var jsonWriter = new JSONWriterClass();
jsonWriter.WriteToString();

// Create a property set to specify format to be GeoJSON
IPropertySet props = new PropertySetClass();
props.SetProperty("Format", "GeoJSON");

var jsonSerializer = new JSONSerializerGdbClass();
jsonSerializer.InitSerializer(jsonWriter, props);

var recordset = new RecordSetClass();
recordset.SetSourceTable((ITable)featureclass, null);

var sr = ((IGeoDataset)featureclass).SpatialReference;

int count;
((IExternalSerializerGdb2)jsonSerializer).WriteRecordSetEx2(null, recordset, null, sr, out count);

var geoJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonWriter.GetStringBuffer());
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea what I needed this for, but I tried your code and it works.