# ArcObjects: Convert Feature to JSON

Tags: arcobjects, json, arcgis-10.6

I need to get the JSON from a feature using ArcObjects. According to  I tried to following code, but it does not work:

```cs
var jsonWriter = new JSONWriterClass();
jsonWriter.WriteToString();

var jsonSerializer = (IExternalSerializerGdb2) new JSONSerializerGdbClass();
var options = new GeometryResultOptionsClass();
var fieldIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, feature.Fields.FieldCount).ToArray();
serializer.WriteRow("", feature, feature.Fields, fieldIndexes, options);
var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonWriter.GetStringBuffer());
```

I allways get the error in the line `serializer.WriteRow("", feature, feature.Fields, fieldIndexes, options)`:

> Value does not fall within the expected range. (Source: ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase)

Does anybody know how to call the `WriteRow(...)` method correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202865/serialize-geometry-to-geojson-with-arcobjects

Comment: It's not asked for GeoJson but for ESRI json and another method is used. Just for a single feature.

Comment: Did you try putting your feature into a `RecordSet` and call `WriteRecordSet` instead?

Comment: Did you try debugging and getting the values of the variables that you are using? It could be as simple as index out of range or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to initialize the serializer. This code might work, at least it did for me:

```cs
var jsonWriter = new JSONWriterClass();
jsonWriter.WriteToString();

var jsonSerializer = new JSONSerializerGdbClass();
jsonSerializer.InitSerializer(jsonWriter, null); // <--
var options = new GeometryResultOptionsClass();
var fieldIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, feature.Fields.FieldCount).ToArray();
((IExternalSerializerGdb2)serializer).WriteRow("", feature, feature.Fields, fieldIndexes, options);
var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonWriter.GetStringBuffer());
```